# Gradle cannot find git.exe on Windows

Tags: android-studio, gradle, git-bash

My Android Studio project uses git from gradle (to include the git SHA-1 in the built artifacts):

```
def getGitVersion = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

On Linux and Mac this works just fine, but on Windows I get the following:

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        ...
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:232)
        ...
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'git'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        ...
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:70)
    ... 4 more
```

I'm using Git Bash, and I've added the path to git.exe to my System *and* User environment variables.
If I start a terminal inside Android Studio, it also has `git.exe` on its path. But when AS launches gradle to build my project, apparently Gradle cannot find `git.exe`.

I can't find any background service or daemon for gradle, thinking that restarting the process after modifying the environment variables might be the problem.
So what could be causing my build.gradle to fail executing git? Does Gradle have its own shell with a custom environment?

Answer (score 2):

Gradle daemon has a clean/empty environment and doesn't inherit the caller's environment.

I do this

```
ext {
   gitExe = 'c:/GIT-2.7.0/bin/git.exe'
}
task clone {
   doLast {
      exec {
         commandLine "cmd /c $gitExe clone https://my-git/project.git".split(' ')
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: System wide environment variables should also apply to the Gradle daemon.

Comment: Well, this defeats the purpose for me since I want this to work on different platforms and machines. If I add it it'll instead break on Linux. I see no reason why gradle is not respecting environment vars?

Comment: @thokuest Right!? I don't see what's gone wrong here.

Comment: @JHH Nonetheless, using `cmd /c` on Windows is considered best practices.

Comment: Have you considered using [Grgit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit)?

Comment: @thokuest Right, in that case I need to tweak my gradle code to use different commands for different platforms. I need to have this working for Windows, Linux and Mac OS.